# Face Grid and Point plot are not giving accurate results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I am working with the Titanic data set of [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data). I am trying to visualize the correlation between all the categorical variables. For this, I am using the point plot together with FaceGrid. Some parts of the plots are contradicting with data.

For generating the pointplot, I used

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(train, row='Embarked', size=2.2, aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.pointplot, 'Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex', palette='deep')
grid.add_legend()
```

The point plot  is showing that almost every male Embarked from 'C' having Pclass =1 and 2 have survived. This is highly unlikely. I tried to verify it using a pivot table:

```
temp = round(pd.pivot_table(train_df, values='Survived', index=['Embarked','Sex'], columns='Pclass', aggfunc=[lambda x: len(x), np.sum,'mean'] ),2)
```

42 from class 1, 
10 from class 2, and 
43 from class 3 have embarked from 'C'.

But only 17, 2, 10 have survived. Therefore the mean probabilities should be 0.40, 0.20, and 0.23.

I think the main issue is the warning it generated:

```
UserWarning: Using the pointplot function without specifying `order` is likely to produce an incorrect plot.
UserWarning: Using the pointplot function without specifying `hue_order` is likely to produce an incorrect plot.
```

[image: Pointplot and the Pivot table]

I do not understand the meaning of *Order* here.
On a side note: How can I sort the Embarked index to say 'S', 'C' and 'Q'.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `pointplot`? Seaborn generally does a good job explaining how the parameters are used

Comment: @paul, i did look into the blog/tutorial of seaborn. I didn't understand the concept of ordering that was referenced in warning.

Comment: no -- i mean the documentation of the function. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot there are examples that use the "order" parameter

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I read the documentation. I added extra parameters to point plot, order = [1,2,3], hue_order = ['male','female']. Can you help me with the second question: I have a multi-index with strings, I want to reorder the index level=0 to {S,C,Q}. I tried reindex, it didnt work.

Comment: there are existing questions about indexing dataframes in such a way